# Getting RemoteAddress from AuthenticationSuccessEvent

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am trying to get the remoteaddress from the client and I get a casterror

```
2019-02-22 18:54:05.104  WARN 21028 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint  : Handling error: ClassCastException, class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

The method is this:

```
@Autowired
private LoginAttemptService loginAttemptService;

public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent e){
    WebAuthenticationDetails auth = (WebAuthenticationDetails) e.getAuthentication().getDetails();
    loginAttemptService.loginSucceeded(auth.getRemoteAddress());
}
```

The `.getDetails()` method returns only the username and grant_type. 
There is no remote address in this object.
I am following this guide here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-block-brute-force-authentication-attempts

Comment: did you find the solution?